# I need to implement a window application and validate users against a SQL DB

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, custom-membershipprovider

Is there a way I could use custom membership provider without need to create an asp service for it?
I prefer validating the users right from within the application exe itself against the DB.
OTOH I still want to have a login form that implements **System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationCredentials** and interact with **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal**, **System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider** or any of all these .NET built-in stuff.

Any good approaches?
I believe I am not the first person who wants to do it, anyone?

Comment: Dude, why do you want to implement a custom membership provider when windows already provides, I think, 3 basic membership providers, plus 2 extended providers that use Kerberos and Certificate signon?

Comment: Cuz I want to have my own MembershipUser structure.
Also my validation rules are different.
I don't want the users to have emails etc. etc.

Comment: how will your custom membership provider talk to your database if you don't use a service of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to wish to talk to the database directly your self, you may be better off just writing your own logon logic.